# Time of closest approach between two balls on different inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

Two balls A and B are simultaneously released on two frictionless inclined plane of equal inclination. the balls pass through same horizontal level after 12 and 4 seconds respectively. how long after they were released they will come closest to each other.
The diagram given in question

Comment: Tip: you should study this to be 2 dimensional plane and find an equation of motion in each axis which will substitute x and y coordinates.

Comment: @Jelly Strawberry, could you please explain?

Comment: Create a 2 dimensional plane based on the motion of each ball. Then find a motion equation which describes the position of each ball in each axis as a function of time.

Comment: I have got X=1/2gt²cotθ.       and.    y=1/2gt²          Then can you please help how to proceed forward @Jelly Strawberry,. and is it right that the ball A rolls down rightwards and ball B leftwards?

Comment: Sorry I cant help you more I am not good at geometry .But follow my instructions. This is how you solve it.

Comment: Yes ball A rolls leftwards and ball B rolls downwards. I really wish I could help you more.

Comment: It is unclear what you don't understand. The general strategy would be to determine the trajectory of the two balls (what are ax, ya, xb and yb as a function of time). For simplicity, presume that b is at the origin at t =0. The general form will be quadratic in time if you need a hint. You will have some unknowns in the formula (angle between plane and horizontal, coordinates of A at t = 0). Using the 4/12 second information, you will remove one . Then, the distance squared is (xa-xb)^2 + (ya-yb)^2. Minimizing this function (as a function of time) will give you the answer.

Comment: There could be also more clever solutions, but my strategy above should work.